# Invalid column in contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-1.6-donut

I am planning to create cursorjoiner for my app. I would like to join the Display name and Email id using the cursorjoiner. I am trying on Android 1.6.

When I query for the Email Id list, I get an exception as :

```
03-30 13:08:15.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column person
```

My code is as below

```
String[] projection1 = new String[] {
People._ID,
People.DISPLAY_NAME
} ;

String[] projection2 = new String[] {
    Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID,
    Contacts.ContactMethods.DATA
} ;

Cursor cur = cr.query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection1, null, null, null);
Cursor emailCur = cr.query( Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI, 
                                projection2, 
                                null, null, null);
```

I checked the docs it says `PERSON_ID` is a valid entry.

Also, if I use the same column as a parameter inside a query it works.

```
emailCur = cr.query( Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI,
                     projection2, 
                     Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID + " = ?", 
                     new String[]{id}, null);
```

Can any one tell what parameter should I use in projection to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) is depreciated, use [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) instead.

Comment: I know that it is deprecated starting from 2.0. I am doing for 1.6. Hence it is still active. Kindly let me know any other way of doing this. Thanks